# Delegate to @RequestMapping by get-query parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is is possible to delegate different `@RequestMapping` methods by evaluation get-query parameter?

Example: if I call `localhost:8080/cars?format=csv` I want to invoke the first method.

But if I call  `localhost:8080/cars?format=anyothervalue` I'd like to invoke the second method. Is that possible in spring using `@RequestParam`s?

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @RequestMapping("/cars", {format == 'csv'})
    public Response doGetCsv(@RequestParam format) {

    }

    @RequestMapping("/cars", {format == 'xml'})
    public Response doGetOthers(@RequestParam format) {

    }
}
```

Comment: just off the bat: format == 'csv' and format != null is ambiguous. For the container both methods are valid if format is 'csv'

Comment: @efekctive thanks for the hint, I modified my example.

Comment: not a problem. you're welcome

Comment: Why don't you use accept headers?